# Regular Expression Help

Tags: .net, regex

I need help in regular expressions, match and replace pattens. I am working on rates.
my rates can be like

```
345.00
456
2345.90
341.34
```

I have to check if the rate ends in 9, if not i have to end the rate with 9 and a $ symbol.

The rates after running the rule should become

```
$349.00
$459.00
$2349.00
$339.00
```

I am storing the rate as string so that it would be easy when I use the `Regex.IsMatch` function.

can someone give me the regular expression for the matchpattern and replace pattern.

I am struggling with this from half a day and need help.

Thanks
Sujatha

Comment: Unclear: you do not explain why `345` becomes `$349` but `341` becomes `$339`: it contradicts your requirement because it changes multiple digits instead of just the ending digit. So you're applying conditions (increasing or decreasing value) that aren't deducible from your examples. For instance, what about `344` and `344.5`: do you round them based on distance to `9` (so `$349`), or based on distance to `0` (so `$339`), or some other rule?

Answer (score 1):

An easier and more intuitive way is to use integer arithmetic:

```
// convert amount to int, then:
amount = amount - (amount % 10) + 9
// or more succintly
amount += 9 - (amount % 10)
```

And that will give you what you want. You can then use `String.Format()` to get the currency formatting:

```
public static String ToMoney(string amount) 
{
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(double.Parse(amount));
    x += 9 - (x%10);
    return String.Format("{0:C}", x);
}
```

**See it in action on [ideone](http://ideone.com/3bRNV)**

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] ss = { "345.00", "456", "2345.90", "341.56" };

foreach (string s in ss)
{
  Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"^(\d*)\d(?:\.\d+)?$",
                                     @"$$${1}9.00"));
}
```

output:

```
$349.00
$459.00
$2349.00
$349.00
```

Initially, `(\d*)` matches as many digits as it can and stores them in capturing group #1 (for example, it matches `341` in `341.56`).  Then it backs off one position to let `\d` match the final digit (group #1 now contains just `34`).  Finally, `(?:\.\d+)?` matches the fraction if there is one (`.56` in this case).

In the substitution, `$$` inserts a dollar sign (`$` has a special meaning in substitutions, so you have to escape it with another `$`).  `${1}` inserts the contents of capturing group #1 (`34` in the case of `341.56`).  Normally you can use just `$1`, but this time the group reference is followed by another digit in the substitution, so it would look like I was referring to group #19.  The braces around the `1` tell it unambiguously I want group #1 followed by `9`.  Finally, `.00` completes the substitution.

That regex you came up uses named capture groups, so you use `${price1}` instead of `${1}` to insert the first part of the number.  The other two capturing groups aren't needed.  In fact, there's a lot of stuff in there that doesn't really belong.  And I see you're removing the fractional part now instead of replacing it with `.00`.

One more thing: you don't need to call `IsMatch()` before starting a replacement; that's taken care of by the `Replace()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use multiple Regexp patterns, since this doesn't seem like it has to work on a lot of input:

First, lets get rid of the float:

```
s/\..*$//
```

Then, let's handle the '9':

```
s/.$/9/
```

Finally, add the '$' and the '.00':

```
s/^/$/
s/$/.00/
```

Comment: There surely is a "better" solution, as in smaller, but you'd have to use backtracking and saved matches, which usually scale less good on the NFA that most Regex-engines umplement.